# Weird problem with GUI programming in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have made a simple GUI in Java. The problem is, when I add label to the frame before buttons and check-buttons I get weird flickering when hovering over buttons, and GUI doesn't look right. But when I add label after buttons and check-buttons everything is working fine. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
package javaapplication13;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
    }
}

class ButtonFrame extends JFrame {
    public ButtonFrame() {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("1. Dugme");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2. Dugme");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
        JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("Prvo dugme");
        JCheckBox c2 = new JCheckBox("Drugo dugme");
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        setTitle("Dugme");
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        this.add(b1);
        this.add(b2);
        this.add(c1);
        this.add(c2);
        this.add(l1);
        b1.setBounds(20, 30, 90, 20);
        b2.setBounds(20,70,90,20);
        l1.setBounds(70,120,90,20);
        c1.setBounds(120,30,120,20);
        c2.setBounds(120,70,120,20);

        l1.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I see no flickering.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start learning that. This was exercise for school, and I have to add some action listeners to the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not see the flickering you claim to be getting when I copied and ran your code on my Windows 10 computer with JDK 17. However, when I changed your code and added the label to the frame before adding the buttons and check-boxes (as you stated in your question), I did see "flickering".

Although you have already accepted @Antoniossss [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686242/weird-problem-with-gui-programming-in-java/69686352#69686352), it is **not** recommended to **not** use a layout manager. Refer to the following excerpts from [Doing Without a Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible.

---

> If a container holds components whose size is not affected by the container's size or by font, look-and-feel, or language changes, then absolute positioning might make sense.

One of the layout managers that your GUI lends itself to is [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), although that is not the only suitable one. The below code shows how. (Note that in the below code I set the text of the `JLabel` so that you can see it.)

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BtnFrame {
    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dugme");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        createForm(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createForm(Container contentPane) {
        if (contentPane instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent jCmpt = (JComponent) contentPane;
            jCmpt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        }
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JButton b1 = new JButton("1. Dugme");
        contentPane.add(b1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("Prvo dugme");
        contentPane.add(c1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2. Dugme");
        contentPane.add(b2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JCheckBox c2 = new JCheckBox("Drugo dugme");
        contentPane.add(c2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("label");
        contentPane.add(l1, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BtnFrame gui = new BtnFrame();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> gui.createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the application.

[image: screen capture of running application]

When setting the layout manager to null in your code (as @Antoniossss said in his answer), the GUI looks like the below screen capture. (Again, I also set the text of the `JLabel` so that you can see it.)

[image: screen capture of OP app]

As you can see, the two screen captures are practically identical.

For completeness, here is your code, with my changes, that produce the above screen capture. As you can see, I moved the line `this.add(l1)` and also added the line `cp.setLayout(null)`.

```java
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ButtonFrame extends JFrame {
    public ButtonFrame(){
        
        JButton b1 = new JButton("1. Dugme");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2. Dugme");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
        JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("Prvo dugme");
        JCheckBox c2 = new JCheckBox("Drugo dugme");
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(null); // Added this line.
        setTitle("Dugme");
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        this.add(l1);
        this.add(b1);
        this.add(b2);
        this.add(c1);
        this.add(c2);
//        this.add(l1);
        b1.setBounds(20, 30, 90, 20);
        b2.setBounds(20,70,90,20);
        l1.setBounds(70,120,90,20);
        c1.setBounds(120,30,120,20);
        c2.setBounds(120,70,120,20);
        
        l1.setText("label");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I see now that i should use layout manager. I started learning this a few days ago, and this is all new to me. I dont have no experience in java. I just know concepts of OOP from my C++ course.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the default `LayoutManager` which you dont want to use anyway since you are using strict bounds on your components. Remove layout manager with

```
 setLayout(null);
```

And it will work as intended

```
public ButtonFrame(){

    setLayout(null); //this will do the trick

    JButton b1 = new JButton("1. Dugme");
    ...rest of your code

}
```